# Visual-Bug: Right side-bar titles

Tags: bug, design, related-questions, linked-questions

Questions with 4 character scores (1000 and higher or negative -100 and lower) in the right sidebar get out of phase. Check the attached screenshot below.

---

[image: zoom to bug]

---

Bug can be seen *best* here: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Tested on Chrome @linux

Comment: Dupe. I'm going to have to search, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer no problem, just bringing it out there